# Animate Element Based On Class Name (many items are sharing the same class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have an online store, and I am required to add an animation that moves the product image to the cart box whenever the user click "Add to cart", the issue is whenever I click "Add to cart" the animation will be applied to all products.

HTML(this is an HTML for one item, all other items are the same):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addToCart").click(function() {
    $(".proImage").animate({
      left: '250px',
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <img src="#" class="proImage">
  <a href="#" class="btnorange addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

How can I make the animation apply only to the selected product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go up to the parent and choose the related `img` using the `this` keyword and `parent()` method :

```
$(this).parent().find(".proImage").animate({
    left: '250px',
});
```

You could also use `closest()` like :

```
$(this).closest('div').find(".proImage").animate({
    left: '250px',
});
```

Using `prev()` method will work two in your case :

```
$(this).prev(".proImage").animate({
  left: '250px',
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addToCart").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).prev(".proImage").animate({
      left: '250px',
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.proImage {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/product.png" class="proImage">
  <a href="#" class="btnorange addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/product.png" class="proImage">
  <a href="#" class="btnorange addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/product.png" class="proImage">
  <a href="#" class="btnorange addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the working snippet in my answer... NOTE the `position: relative;` rule if you want to change the position using `left;right;top;bottom` attributes

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".addToCart").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.proImage').animate({
             left: '250px',
         });
    });
});
```